Is Swift Testing Available on iOS 15 / Xcode 15?
I’m planning to integrate the new Swift Testing framework into my iOS application. My minimum deployment target is iOS 15, and I wanted to know if Swift Testing is fully compatible with this version of iOS.
Specifically, I’m concerned about:

Any potential limitations when using Swift Testing features on iOS 15.
If certain features of Swift Testing (like concurrency, new assertions, or reflection) require a newer iOS version or tooling that might not be supported on iOS 15.
Any known issues or workarounds when using Swift Testing with this iOS version.


Swift Testing does not depend on iOS versions. It requires Swift 6+ and Xcode 16+.

Swift Testing does not depend on the minimum deployment target, simply because tests are not deployed to users of your app.
From the documentation, Swift Testing just requires Swift 6+ and Xcode 16+. This does mean there is a minimum OS version requirement for the machine that is running the tests. Xcode 16 is not compatible with macOS versions earlier than 14.5.
